# Elasticsearch throws error with two mappings in index template

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

If I define an index template file *template.json* as follows:

```
{
    "template": "types",
    "mappings": {
        "type1": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        },
        "type2": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and try post it:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_template/types -d@template.json
```

I get this response:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "mapper [title] cannot be changed from type [keyword] to [text]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "mapper [title] cannot be changed from type [keyword] to [text]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I expect to be able to define multiple mappings within a template with different fields with different types.

What am I doing or assuming incorrectly?

I am using Elasticsearch 5.6.

Answer (score 3):

If the fields have the same name, they need to be of the same field type, even if you are using version 5.6, which is the last one to allow the use of multiple mapping types in the same index.

If the field `title` in the type `type1` is mapped as a `text`, the field `title` in the type `type2` also needs to be mapped as a `text`.

Comment: Do you have a source for this info?

Comment: Found it: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/mapping.html#mapping-type

Comment: Thanks, everything is behaving more logically now that I understand that. :)